# Can any one explain the functionality of this code,please?

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, sentiment-analysis, sequential

Can any one explain the functionality of this code,please?

```
embedding_vector_length = 32 model = Sequential() 
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size,embedding_vector_length, 
input_length=200) ) model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.25)) 
model.add(LSTM(50, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5)) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2)) model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) 
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 
print(model.summary())
```

Answer (score 0):

This code defines a recurrent neural network (often referred to as a 'Sequence' or 'Sequential' model). In this context is is being set up for natural language processing with a binary cross entropy loss function, adam optimizer, and two dropout layers.